# Render CSV parsed with Papaparse into HTML

Tags: html, angular, ionic3, papaparse

I'm working with Ionic 3 and I need to visualize a CSV in my app. I used Papaparse to read the file and I got them with `console.log(this.csvData)`.

[image: my 2 arrays with the info]

But I can't show them in the HTML file (the space in blank should show the table with the info). All I want is a table with the info of the CSV file local store and I do not know if I correctly used `*ngFor` with my array `csvData` because its seems `headerRow` is empty when calling `let row of headerRow` in `*ngFor`. I'm using Ionic 3 with Angular 5.

This is my .ts file :

```
export class myPage {
csvData: any[] = [];
headerRow: any[] = [];
url = 'assets/json/data.csv'; 
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:
    NavParams, private httpClient: HttpClient, 
    public modalController: ModalController) {
        this.extract() 
}
private extract(){
Papa.parse(this.url, {
  download: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    this.csvData=results.data;  
    this.headerRow = this.csvData[0]; 
    this.csvData.splice(0, 1); 
    console.log(this.csvData);  
    console.log(this.headerRow);  
    }
});
}
}
```

This is part of my HTML file :

```
<ion-item>
<ion-scroll  class="data-scroll">
    <table  class="data-table">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let row of headerRow; let i = index" text-center><b> {{ row }} </b></td>
          </tr>    
          <tr *ngFor="let row of csvData; let i = index">
            <td *ngFor="let data of row; let j = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
              <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="csvData[i][j]"></ion-input>
            </td>
        </table>
      </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: `<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="csvData[i][j]"></ion-input>`  why are you using variable `csvData` here ? are you trying to make it editable ?

Comment: the above code seems to work check the demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccblnz

Comment: sorry my mistake, I should delete it, I was following an tutorial.
It didn't work for me, but I realize that if I show my csvData array in html {{ csvData }}  its empty. I think its a problem loading the page faster than making the parse. Maybe I need something like Promise. @JoelJoseph